# PHP form that loads content based on dropdown list option

Tags: php, html, if-statement, switch-statement

Referring to this example [PHP form that loads content based on dropdown option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599580/php-form-that-loads-content-based-on-dropdown-option/24599679#24599679)

Solution 1, PHP

1) index form

```
<form action="loadPage.php" method="POST" name="theForm" id="theForm">
<select form="theForm" name="selectedPage">
  <option value="page_1">Page 1</option>
  <option value="page_2">Page 2</option>
  ...
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Load page" />
</form>
```

2) A PHP handler

```
<?php
//loadPage.php
$requested_page = $_POST['selectedPage'];

switch($requested_page) {
  case "page_1":
    header("Location: page_1.php");
  break;
  case "page_2":
    header("Location: page_2.php");
  break;
  default :
  echo "No page was selected";
  break;
}
?>
```

I just want to do It without the need of clicking on submit. I want to achieve this just by clicking on the dropdown list value then checks if it's equal to the value in the Php file if yes show the page.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just do it via. jQuery's change-function and Ajax. You can detect if the users selected the option and send it via. Ajax to the backend. The PHP script should return a reponse in JSON and the front-end can handle it.

Comment: I assume you absolutely *must* do this in PHP for whatever reason, but it would be a much better solution to examine the form & show/hide content entirely client-side using JavaScript, without needing to send requests to the server to run your PHP code.  If you're actually *not* explicitly restricted to doing this with PHP, I highly discourage you from doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write html as follow:

```
<select form="theForm" name="selectedPage" onchange="this.form.submit()">
  <option value="page_1">Page 1</option>
  <option value="page_2">Page 2</option>
</select>
```

This will submit form when you select option.

Comment: This is much better than the other answer. The code is simpler, and also one should not have to implement multiple php files for each option in the list... that's a maintainability nightmare.

Answer (score 3):

This will cause a "redirect" when you select an option in the dropdown:

Add an `onchange` event to the `select` to change the current browser location.

Change the select option values to the URLs for the pages.

(You might then drop the PHP header directions in `loadPage.php`. Not needed anymore.)

```
<select form="theForm" name="selectedPage" 

        onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">

  <option value="page_1.php">Page 1</option>
  <option value="page_2.php">Page 2</option>
</select>
```

---

**Answers for the questions asked by Jay Blanchard in the comment section:**

> Can this be done without inline JavaScript (for ease of maintenance and reuse-ability)?

Sure, thats possible, too. For instance, with jQuery:

```
$('#SelectId').change(function() { 
    //alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
    window.location.href = 'http://' + this.value;
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/change

Or you may bind with `.on('change')`

```
$('#SelectId').on('change', function() {
    //alert( this.value ); // or $(this).val()
    window.location.href = 'http://' + this.value;
});
```

> Can you do it without jQuery?

Sure, thats possible, too. You might select the element by using `document.getElementById()` and bind the event handling with `addEventListener`.

```
window.onload = function() { 
    var select = document.getElementById('SelectId');
    var handler = function() {
      if(select.value) {
            window.location.href = 'http://' + select.value;
      }
    };
    select.addEventListener('change', handler, false);
};
```

Comment: Can this be done without inline JavaScript (for ease of maintenance and reuse-ability)?

Comment: Sure, thats possible, too. For instance, with jQuery: `$('#SelectId').change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});`. See https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Can you do it without jQuery?

Comment: Sure. I've updated my answer and added an example without jQuery.

Comment: Awesome. The reason that I asked is in my first comment as I am trying to get folks to earn how to avoid inline JS (progressive enhancement, et. al.). That is my +1 on your answer.

Comment: Thanks all. I will look into this but I want now an easy quick solution. you are all awesome.